# Display VF Page Using onmouseover of Custom Field

Tags: visualforce, mousehover

I have a custom field on the Opportunity which right now is a hyperlink for an embedded image (help question mark).  The hyperlink works fine, but it opens a new tab in the browser to my VF page.  Instead, I would like the field to display my visualforce page when the user hovers over the image in my custom field.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  I need to use this approach instead of the standard help text because I have over 1,000 characters to display.

***Current Custom Field:***

```
HYPERLINK("/apex/VF_LostHelpTxt",IMAGE("/img/alohaSkin/help_orange.png","",25,25))
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want an info window to come up when they hover over a link?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: You probably need to use this Jquery plugin. http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content

Comment: Can I include that in a custom field or do I need to create an embedded VF page for it?

Comment: you mean content from a custom field?

Comment: When the user goes to the edit page of the Opportunity, I need them to be able to hover over the ? icon and see the text in my custom VF page.  I am not familiar with jQuery so I'm not sure if I need to put that in a custom formula field with my ? icon or an embedded VF page.

Comment: Ohhh, you are trying to do it on the standard edit page.. you are unable to do that. I misunderstood. I thought you had a visualforce page that you use to edit the opportunity.